# Why is ".html" appearing on the end of my urls in browser?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

So I uploaded a site to a webhosting and now when I'm checking it, every page except the home has .html ending, like this:

xxxxxxxx.com/xxx.html

How can I remove it? And how do I then link to these pages in href?

Comment: What are you using to serve html files?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it display the .html?

Comment: Danizavtz Site is pure HTML and CSS. Not sure this answers the question.

ATP I tried those and the (.)html still remained.

J08691 - I don't know, looks strange in my opinion.

Comment: One of those solutions helped, thanks @ATP.